# Is it possible to do in XAML part like as all i have done in code behind part?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I Mean can I do all operation in XAML with out using code behind.

Comment: its not clear in ur question wat u want to do. Plz elaborate it.

Comment: yup rubyraj, I need to do all operation in xaml without using code behind. But I need all operation whatever we do in code behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea behind XAML was to separate presentation from business logic. Mixing those two concepts in the same file would be bad. Also writing C#/VB.NET code in a XML file could quickly turn into a nightmare. With the MVVM pattern you don't even need to setup explicitly the event handlers in the XAML. Not to mention the unit testability and maintainability of the application. Simply put: use the right gun for the right task.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Except if you need some UI logic. for exa if you want to do some thing particular when some event get fired from UI.

Comment: you can even do this in xaml i think

Comment: @Xin: What I meant was that we can not implement the bussiness logic or UI logic after the event fired. Yes, we can define the event handler in Xaml. did you mean same or otherwise?

Comment: You can still use behaviors to achieve this.